# Spring Security Authentication and User Interfaces

Tags: spring, spring-security

According to Spring Security, Authentication Provider is used if the authentication is done by an external Authentication Provider. After Authentication, Spring Security will get the Authentication object which encapsulates the user information.

If Spring Security framework authenticates, the user information is encapsulated in an instance of User interface (for example UserDetails class which is a default implementation).

My question is - why Spring Security framework couldn't use a consistent approach? Why they could not use UserDetails instead of Authentication object for all the cases? Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

**According to Spring documentation**

```
public interface Authentication extends Principal, Serializable
```

Represents the token for an authentication request or for an authenticated principal once the request has been processed by the AuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication) method.
Once the request has been authenticated, the Authentication will usually be stored in a thread-local SecurityContext managed by the SecurityContextHolder by the authentication mechanism which is being used. An explicit authentication can be achieved, without using one of Spring Security's authentication mechanisms, by creating an Authentication instance and using the code:

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(anAuthentication);
```

For more details, refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html

**Explanation:**

Authentication object will be set to local security context only if the user is authenticated with valid credentials. And it acts as a token. Where as in case of UserDetails we can't get to know if the user is authenticated.

You can also look at it as a Single Responsibility Principle, Where UserDetails class resposnibility is to manage user details, Authentication Responsibility is to handle authenticity.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Thanks Pradys, makes sense. So can I assume that Spring Security might internally create an Authentication object and set it in the security context internally if we use UserDetails?

Comment: @SRaj Yes, Spring will internally create authentication object and sets in the context. But if you write your own authentication filter then you need to manually set the authentication object to the context. Please give a up-vote or accept the answer if it serves your query.